# Generating Brainf*** NOPs

Tags: code-golf, random, brainfuck, code-generation, balanced-string

Sometimes when writing brainfuck code, you feel the need to make it longer than needed to *encourage* debugging. You could do it by just plopping a `><` in there, but what fun is that? You'll need something longer and less NOPey to confuse anybody reading your code.

### Quick introduction to Brainfuck

> [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is an esoteric programming language created in 1993 by Urban Müller, and notable for its extreme minimalism. (Wikipedia)

Brainfuck is a language based on eight commands: `+-><,.[]`. The code is run on something like a Turing machine: an infinite tape on which values can be changed. In this challenge, we'll focus on the first four:

```
+    increment the value at the pointer
-    decrement the value at the pointer
>    move the pointer right
<    move the pointer left
```

### Brainfuck NOPs

A brainfuck NOP is a sequence of brainfuck characters that, when executed from any state, leads to no change in the state. They consist of the four characters mentioned above.

### The Challenge

The challenge is to write a program or function that, when executed, generates a random brainfuck NOP of the given length.

### Input

You will receive as input a nonnegative even integer `n`. (NOPs are impossible for odd `n`.)

### Output

You will output a random brainfuck NOP of the length `n`.

### Rules

- The definition of NOP: when the output of the program is inserted at any point in a brainfuck program, the behavior of said program must not change in any way. In other words, it must not change the state of the interpreter.

  - Note that for example `+>-<` is incorrect, since it changes the values of the two cells without changing them back. Please test your solution for these before posting.
  - Also note that `+>-<->+<` is a NOP that can't be reduced to nothing just by removing `><` `<>` `+-` `-+`. Thus, you can't use an algorithm that just inserts these inside each other.
- Every valid NOP of the length `n` must have a nonzero chance of appearing in the output. The distribution does not have to be uniform, though.
- The brainfuck interpreter in question has a doubly infinite tape of arbitrary precision cells. That is, you can go infinitely to the both directions, and increment/decrement each cell indefinitely.
- The program must finish **within 1 minute for `n` = 100** on my machine, so no generating all possible NOPs and picking one.
- If given invalid input (non-integer, negative, odd, etc.) you may do anything you'd like, including crash.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Examples

Here are all valid outputs for `n` = 4:

```
++--    +-+-    +--+    --++    -+-+    -++-
>><<    ><><    ><<>    <<>>    <><>    <>><
><+-    ><-+    <>+-    <>-+
>+-<    >-+<    <+->    <-+>
+><-    -><+    +<>-    -<>+
+-><    -+><    +-<>    -+<>
```

Here are a few possible outputs for `n` = 20:

```
+>>->+<->-<<<->>++<<
>+>-<+<->+-<>->+<-<+
+--+-++--++-+--+-++-
>>>>>>>>>+-<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: here's a brainfuck NOP that doesn't use `+-<>` like you asked for: `a`

Comment: I don't think non-simple NOPs exist, so you can probably remove that qualification. `.` has a side-effect, `,` overwrites a value which cannot be recovered without the use of `[]`. But `[]` will end up setting a value to zero. This also overwrites a value (so we'd need another `[]` to recover it) unless we can be sure that the affected cell was zero to begin with. However, we'd have to search for such a cell with something like `[>]`, and it's impossible to reliably return to the position we came from.

Comment: `<` at the start of a BF programm gives different results depending on interpreter, is it safe to say we start at position 100 so we definetly dont run ito that error?

Comment: @Eumel "The brainfuck interpreter in question has a doubly infinite tape of arbitrary precision cells."

Comment: Please note that ["Brainfuck" is no longer allowed in question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238581/287795) on the system level. It appears you were able to circumvent the restriction by using non-ASCII characters. In the future, please abide by this restriction.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail, that's not an operation, just a comment taking zero execution time.  A compiler would strip it out.

Comment: I'd love to see someone post an answer to this in brainfuck

Comment: @hand-e-food you're no fun

Comment: @patrick brainfuck can't do random

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Well, it's Turing complete... so technically one could write a PRNG in it just like any other language. (Although seeding it might be hard.)

Comment: Just seed it with 0, what's wrong with settling for pseudo-random? That satisfies the requirement, does it not?

Comment: No, because it'd always produce the same output if the seed was constant

Comment: You could execute the code and pipe in the current date/time as an input to be used as the seed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### CJam, <s>62</s> 59 bytes

*Thanks to nhahtdh for saving 3 bytes.*

Because there is no requirement for any particular distribution as long as each no-op appears with finite probability, we can simplify this a lot by simply generating string containing a balanced number of `-+` and `<>`, respectively, testing if it's a NOP and sorting it if it isn't.

Of course, for longer inputs, this will almost always result in sorted output, but you can test the code with some input like `8` to see that it can in principle produce any NOP of the given length.

```
ri_0a*\2/{;"-+<>":L2/mR}%smr:SL["Xa.Xm"3/2e*L]z:sers~0-S$S?
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmlfMGEqXDIvezsiLSs8PiI6TDIvbVJ9JXNtcjpTTFsiWGEuWG0iMy8yZSpMXXo6c2Vyc34wLVMkUz8&input=MTAw)

Comment: Yes... the arbitrary limit should have been n=1000 under 10 seconds. Computers are just way to fast today ^^ Because the algorithmic answer solves it in under a second even for n = 1000

Comment: For even larger n, I think it's possible to just sort the output if the balanced string is not NOP. The distribution is terribly skewed, but it's allowed by the question.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ that's a neat idea.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Thanks, that actually saves three bytes here as well.

Answer (score 17):

### CJam, <s>118</s> 116 bytes

This got slightly out of hand... especially the second half seems like it should be very golfable.

```
ri2/_)mr:R-"<>"R*mr_'=fm0\{1$+}%+__&e`]:\{mr1aa..+}*\@](\z:~\{~\("+-"*mr1$3$e=[{_,)mr_2$<@@>}*+]@@f{`1$`={(}@?\}W<}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri2%2F_)mr%3AR-%22%3C%3E%22R*mr_'%3Dfm0%5C%7B1%24%2B%7D%25%2B__%26e%60%5D%3A%5C%7Bmr1aa..%2B%7D*%5C%40%5D(%5Cz%3A~%5C%7B~%5C(%22%2B-%22*mr1%243%24e%3D%5B%7B_%2C)mr_2%24%3C%40%40%3E%7D*%2B%5D%40%40f%7B%601%24%60%3D%7B(%7D%40%3F%5C%7DW%3C%7D%2F&input=100)

This handles `N = 100` pretty much instantly. I don't have time to write the full breakdown of the code now, so here is the algorithm:

- Generate a random balanced string of `<` and `>` with random (even) length between `0` and `N` inclusive.
- Riffle the tape head positions into this array. E.g. `"<>><"` becomes `[0 '< -1 '> 0 '> 1 '< 0]`.
- Get a list of all positions reached in the process.
- For each such position initialise an empty string. Also determine how many pairs of characters are left to reach a string of length `N`.
- For each remaining pair append `+-` to the string of a random position.
- Shuffle all of those strings.
- For each position determine how often that position occurs in the riffled array, and split the corresponding string into that many (random-length) chunks.
- In the riffled array, replace the occurrences of the position with its random chunks.

Done. This is based on the observation that:

- Any NOP must have an equal amount of `<` and `>` to return the tape head to the original position.
- The code will be a NOP as long as each tape cell is incremented as often as decremented.

By distributing random but balanced amounts of `+`s and `-`s between all the places where the tape head is on a given cell, we ensure that we find every possible NOP.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 350 bytes

```
Quiet@(For[a="+",If[{##4}=={},#3!=0||Union@#!={0},Switch[#4,"+",#0[ReplacePart[#,#2->#[[#2]]+1],#2,#3,##5],"-",#0[ReplacePart[#,#2->#[[#2]]-1],#2,#3,##5],">",#0[#~Append~0,#2+1,#3+1,##5],"<",If[#2<2,#0[#~Prepend~0,1,#3-1,##5],#0[#,#2-1,#3-1,##5]]]]&@@{{0},1,0}~Join~Characters@a,a=""<>RandomSample@Flatten@RandomChoice[{{"+","-"},{">","<"}},#/2]];a)&
```

Way too long? Yes. Do I even care? Not until someone else posts a valid answer.

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation, so people can actually convince themselves this is valid? :)

Comment: How exactly *does* this work? If I call the function with a number it only returns `+`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Fixed... Currently, it just generates random programs with an equal number of `+`-`-` and `<`-`>` pairs until one happens to be a NOP. Half of it is taken by a simple BF interpreter.

Comment: does that actually generate a valid no-op of length 100 in under a minute?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes. On average, I would say that it takes about 5 seconds. At first, I tried completely random programs, but it never terminated for length 100.

Comment: Sadly, that might be shorter in CJam than my current solution.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Also, `RepeatedTiming` gave me an average of 8 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 163 bytes

```python
from random import*
n=int(input())
p=0;d=[0]*n;a=choices(b'+-<>',k=n)
for c in a:d[p]+=c%2*(44-c);p+=~c%2*(c-61)
if p|any(d):a=n//2*b'+-'
print(*map(chr,a),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BbsIwEETv/oq9VGs7iQgUVSjp9kcQh8VOFItmvTJBKlLVX0@B02gOb97ofZmyvK9J9LYAwTfP58gdHtAMP0OwiLiOJc9QWOIj0qy5LN4IJVnsi7LOGaW2j3RsT156pjDlFIarPWPVfH5hfSFxZswFAiQB7uJRTxWFt523@30TXK8V/b1qaD62zqQR9JflbqPrmGSz2fnnFBotT6ufWW2YSs2uvg5KiG59/AQP29at/w)

Full program that prints results to STDOUT. The line that runs BF code might be golfable.

Adopted Tyilo's approach; if the generated BF code is not a NOP, discard it altogether and fall back to `'+-'` repeated.

Comment: Timeout for n=100

Comment: @l4m2 Didn't notice that requirement. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 177 bytes

```python
from random import*
n=int(input())
r=[0]*n*3
p=0
a=[43,45]
s=choices(a+[60,62],k=n)
for c in s:p+=~c%2*(c-61);r[p]+=c%2*(44-c)
if any(r+[p]):s=a*(n//2)
print(*map(chr,s),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY67DoMwDAD3fEWWqnEIKoWUoZW/BDFEaRFRhWM5dGDpr9PHdNLdcrytc6Zu3yfJi5ZA9y/SwllWqwgTrSYRv1YDoASHZrRkO8XYqICD75y/jKpgnHOKj2JCNfSN69vRPZFATVl01Il0uXKF73horYl1f4abDDxW@Bfe1xFUmnSgzUj1DXAtGKyh06kFxfJ7sEtgE2dxBVx5MB6PsO/@Aw)

I used code from Bubbler's answer for the BF simulation.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 160 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...s=c(i=n,t=c(n/2,r=[],f=_=>'+-'),f=_=>'+-<>'[Math.random()*4|0])].map(_=>_<'<'?(r[i]=_+1-~r[i]-1):(i+=_<'>'||-1))|r.some(eval)|i-n?t:s;c=n=>n?c(n-1)+f():r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU5BasMwELz3I5IqW7FDTrbXvuXWFwhhhGI3KrZkJDWXqP26u4HSayl0D7MzzDDMm77paILdUun8ZdrPsDvopRAigqEWXJHwu8OxCCBVMcMIPeElYT@064l80ekqgnYXv1L2fMqVYkqseqMYGTvSkYEGaRWMvC4/H6ysWUMtBzR7kjNKloOIfp3odNMLy7Z0Q2piawDnuAEnYIbPlDVhb5/i@wr3j3b2gRqXoGoRu7rCezDOGQbklgKcacUUfCvF65zr1ngX/TKJxb9SdNif6o7/W3f6vW7/Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 224 bytes

```
(s=RandomSample[##&@@@Table["<"">",(r=RandomInteger)[#/2]]];While[(g=Length@s)<#,s=Insert[s=Insert[s,"+",i=r@g+1],"-",RandomChoice@@Select[GatherBy[0~Range~++g,Count[#,"<"]-Count[#,">"]&@Take[s,#]&],!FreeQ[#,i]&]+1]];""<>s)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BasMwEER/xV2BsfGGOLnGNiKBhkAPbVPoQeigOIssGstBUg@95NfdLSntbYYZZt@OJg00muR6Mz8H55Oai9i@Gn@exqMZrxdSQuRSyjdzYg0NQAdYhN/KwSeyFEollmut9eZ9cNwqbPtE3qZBxrIRGNuDjxSS@hcIFaBrg7TVSiMsAO97u2FyPUl5pAv1Se1/6ML2S9U3zi3dqsribvpkTIHMohd/pgOdM@QH8bjQucaHx0D0wpFjx1f0BqDpYpnP2VJm93dWNWbrmqP5Gw)

Here is the un-golfed (or rather, pre-golfed) version:

```
Function[{n},
 k = RandomInteger[n/2];
 s = RandomSample[## & @@@ Table["<" ">", k]];
 While[Length[s] < n,
   s = Insert[s, "+", i = RandomInteger[Length[s]] + 1];
   p = GatherBy[Range[0, Length[s]], 
     Count[#, "<"] - Count[#, ">"]& @ Take[s, #]&];
   j = RandomChoice @@ Select[p, ! FreeQ[#, i] &]];
   s = Insert[s, "-", j + 1];
   ];
 ""<>s]
```

We first pick a random number of `<`'s and `>`'s to use, and generate a random list with an equal number of each.

To fill in the rest of the characters, we pick a position in which to add a `+`, then find a position where the pointer points to the same location and add a `-` there.

Repeat until the list has length `n`, and stringify the result.